# Return 0 if no record is found

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have written q query in which a transaction is calculated , but of no row is found it should give 0 in the column . my query

```
 Select
  ((Select
    Sum(TxEntryDetails.amt)
  From
    TxEntryDetails
  Where
    TxEntryDetails.crdr = "DR" And
    TxEntryDetails.lcode = LedgerTab.lcode) - (Select
    Sum(TxEntryDetails.amt)
  From
    TxEntryDetails
  Where
    TxEntryDetails.crdr = "CR" And
    TxEntryDetails.lcode = LedgerTab.lcode)) + LedgerTab.opbalance,
  LedgerTab.lname As lname1
From
  LedgerTab
```

here if there is no record in TxEntryDetails it is returning a blank value but i neet 0 so that  i can do further calculation .

Comment: Have you tried using `IsNull` ?

Comment: i tried but it is giving a syntax error

Comment: http://allenbrowne.com/QueryPerfIssue.html might be worth a read

Comment: IIF(... IS NULL,...)

Comment: IsNull(Sum(TxEntryDetails.amt),0) should do it.

Answer (score 0):

`NVL(TxEntryDetails.amt, 0)` instead of just `TxEntryDetails.amt` should do the trick .
NVL function replaces a null value with your given alternative . In this case with 0.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever method you use to check for NULL in existing rows, you also need to check the whole expression for NULL (in case no rows are returned). For example:

```
SELECT (IIF(Sum1 IS NULL,0,Sum1) - IIF(Sum2 IS NULL,0,Sum2)) + opbalance, lname1 FROM 
(
Select 
  (Select
    Sum(IIF(TxEntryDetails.amt IS NULL,0,TxEntryDetails.amt))
    From
    TxEntryDetails
    Where
    TxEntryDetails.crdr = "DR" And
    TxEntryDetails.lcode = LedgerTab.lcode)  AS Sum1,
  (Select
   Sum(IIF(TxEntryDetails.amt IS NULL,0,TxEntryDetails.amt))
   From
   TxEntryDetails
   Where
   TxEntryDetails.crdr = "CR" And
   TxEntryDetails.lcode = LedgerTab.lcode) AS Sum2,
  LedgerTab.opbalance,
  LedgerTab.lname As lname1
From
  LedgerTab
)
```